# setting properties value by api call on application startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

If I have some global config properties value that want to set on application start up, one of the ways to do is by setting it in application.properties and then using @Value to inject those values. However, if I want to set the values by making an API call to get those properties value on application start up and then set the values (but want to use similar way as @Value), rather than getting and setting it via properties files, how should it be achieved ?

```
@Configuration
public class config {
  @Value("${properties1}")
  private String properties1;

  @Value("${properties2}")
  private String properties2;

}
```

I have done some web search on custom property source (https://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#customizing-bootstrap-property-sources), and tried to follow the example, but encountered the error that the placeholder could not be resolved. How to get back the value ?

Could not resolve placeholder 'property.from.sample.custom.source' in value "${property.from.sample.custom.source}"

```
@Configuration
public class CustomPropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> locate(Environment environment) {
        return new MapPropertySource("customProperty",
                Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("property.from.sample.custom.source", "worked as intended"));
    }

}

@Service
public class MainService {

    @Value("${property.from.sample.custom.source}")
    private String value;

    public void printValue() {
        System.out.println("value - " + value);
    }

}
```

Comment: In Spring Boot, properties are retrieved from Property Sources, so if you want to implement an alternate way for Spring Boot to load properties, you need to implement a custom property source. Do a web search for [`spring boot custom propertysource`](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+boot+custom+propertysource) to start your **research** into how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Spring Boot, you can run the Spring Boot application and pass the arguments using the following Maven command (depends on the Spring Boot version):

- **Spring Boot 1.x:** using `-Drun.arguments`:

  `spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=--properties1=One,--properties2=Two`
- **Spring Boot 2.x:** using `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments`:

  `spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--properties1=One,--properties2=Two`

Now you can access the values using the `@Value` annotation:

```
@Value("${properties1}")
private String properties1;

@Value("${properties2}")
private String properties2;
```

**Note:** Once the properties are defined in the properties files (ex. `application.properties` and/or `application-dev.yml` etc..), defined in the command line like above, they can be accessed through the `@Value` annotation.

Baeldung's website offers a nice article: [Command-Line Arguments in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments).

Comment: In what way does this help loading properties through an API call, which is what the question is about?

Comment: @Andreas: As far as I understand, the OP doesn't want to set the values through the API call.

Comment: *"making an API call to get those properties value on application start up"* The property values used by Spring should be retrieved using an API call, as opposed to the normal load from property file and/or taken from the command-line.

Comment: *"API call to get those properties"* - use the REST endpoint (notice the **"get'** word). The question, as I understand, is primarily about **setting** the value: *"However, if I want to set the values programmatically"* - this could be done my way. How do you understnad the question then?

Comment: *"similar way as @Value"* I read this as I just said: the properties, used e.g. by `@Value`, should be programmatically retrieved from a server (using API call), instead of (or in addition to) being loaded from property files (and the other standard places Spring supports).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we can set values to properties file after application is up. Because properties file will be injected to `@Bean` when application is running. But we can hack this.

First, Create a file that contains all the configuration file which will be load from properties file. This file will be our template and initial / default values of the configuration.

Let say we have below configuration as `application.yml`

```
config:
  name: Anna
  age: 18
```

Then create configuration file

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public class ConfigProperties {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to modify our Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigProperties::class)
public class Application { ... }
```

Through here, we can just `@Autowire` the config class to get the value we want, rather than using a `@Value`.

Through here we already have the properties value to our config class. Then if you want to update the properties value (now already on config file) through an API, do a simple `setName(...)`.

But, we have to be aware that this way is only work on a single run. When we restart the application, the value will use the default from properties file.